# Implementação de sistema de pagamento com cartão de crédito

Tags: aplicação-web, e-commerce, pagamento-online

Olá.
Minha dúvida é *"simples"*:

**Existe alguma forma de implementar - em uma aplicação web - o pagamento com cartão de crédito (Visa, MasterCard, etc), sem utilizar recursos de terceiros (PayPal, PagSeguro, etc)?**

No caso, há a possibilidade de integração direta com as empresas de cartão de crédito?

Pesquisei bastante, e não encontrei resposta plausível para o meu questionamento.
Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ligação mais próxima que você poderia conseguir seria com a Cielo. Que depende de contrato, adequação do código e parece que aprovação do código.